# How to enable line numbers in minted for code blocks with more than 2 lines?

Tags: minted, line-numbering

I tend to use the same setting throughout my document. So, I have the following:

```latex
\usepackage[outputdir=build_dir]{minted}
\setminted{
    xleftmargin=2em,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    breaklines,
    baselinestretch=1,
    bgcolor=minted_block_bg,
    linenos=true
}
```

My only problem is I sometimes have code blocks with just 1 or 2 lines and it makes no sense to have line numbers enabled for those. I would like to continue using the default setting in the code above, but I want to be able to enable line numbers only for code blocks with more than 2 lines, for example. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is your question how to set options for specific code blocks that overwrite the default setting (answer: use `\begin{minted}[linenos=false]{language}` for your specific block) or is your question how to automatically disable line numbers for blocks with a small number of lines?

Comment: @Marijn, my question is "how to automatically disable line numbers for blocks with a small number of lines".